# Chrome extension to replace html words

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to create a google extension that will allow me to replace a specific word in a sites html. Ex: replace the word "hidden" with "shown". I am not trying to change page text, just the html. I would like to make it a toggle type extension that I can use when needed. Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Comment: What's your question? What have you already done and where are you stuck?

Comment: How do I go about coding an extension to replace specific words in a site's html with desired ones?

Comment: The point of the extension would be for me to edit out the word "hidden" in a site's html with a push of a button (the extension). So that I could view specific information I need without manually having to remove the word every time I need it for a site.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer with this [blog tutorial](https://9to5google.com/2015/06/14/how-to-make-a-chrome-extensions/). Here's a sample code of how to replace a specific text into another word.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/[word or phrase to replace here]/gi, '[new word or phrase]');

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!