# JavaScript: Replacing (all) certain words on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am having trouble with some code for a chrome extension. The code is supposed to replace a word with another one. It does this, however, I would only like it to replace a word if it is within certain tags such as `<p></p>` or header tags. At the moment it replaces all the words in the HTML file within the `<body></body>`. This sometimes interferes with the HTML code and can break certain features of a website. Here's what I have currently.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(newRegExp("old", "g"), "new");
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688518/chrome-extension-to-replace-html-words

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace words in the body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/replace-words-in-the-body-text)

Answer (score 1):

So just loop over all the elements that you care about and do the replacement on those elements only.

```js
// Get all the elements that you care about into an array
let elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("p, header"));

// Loop over the items in the array
elements.forEach(function(el){
  // Do the replace on the element
  el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/text/g, "letters");
});
```

```html
<header>This is some text in a header</header>
<h1>This is some text in an h1</h1>
<div>This is some text in a div</div>
<p>This is some text in a p</p>
<div>This is some text in a div</div>
<div>This is some text in a div
   <p>This text is inside of a p with lots of text</p>
</div>
```